# Why can't I have a user prompted varaible be the array size?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args)  { 
        int i = 1;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // prompts the user to get how many numbers need to be sorted
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of data points: ");
        int data = input.nextInt();
        // this creates the new array and data sets how large it is
        int [] userArray = new int[data];
        // this clarifies that the value is above 0 or else it will not run
        if (data < 0) {
            System.out.println("The number should be positive. Exiting.");
        }
        // once a value over 0 is in, the loop will start to get in all user data
        else {
            System.out.println("Enter the data:"); 
        }

        while (i <= data) {
            int userInput = input.nextInt();
            userArray[i] = userInput;
            i++;
        }

        // this calls the sortArray method to sort the values entered
        sortArray(userArray);
        // this will print the sorted array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userArray));
    }
}
```

I have set the array size equal to what the user inputs for how many variables they will be entering to be sorted. For some reason, Java only wants a set number instead of the number that is entered by the user. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? *"Java only wants a set number instead of the number that is entered by the user"* is hard to understand.

Comment: Java doesn't want anything. And you can create an array of a variable size.  BTW There is no point checking if the size is invalid AFTER attempting to create the array.

Comment: Arrays start at an index of 0 and the last element is `data.length - 1`

Comment: @Gendarme If i put a 10 or any number within the [ ] part of the line 'int [] userArray = new int[data];' then it will work. When I put in data for the length of the array, it will not work.

Comment: How do you know it is not working?

Comment: @PeterLawrey `userArray.length - 1`, not `data.length - 1`.

Comment: @Gendarme when I run the program with [data] for the length, it outputs: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Comment: You should have provided us with that information right away. It is crucial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there are a few mistakes in your code. You are checking `if(data < 0)` *after* you create your array with `int[] userArray = new int[data];`. You should check it before.

Furthermore, you *will* get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `userArray[data]` does not exist. Array indices start at 0, so the last index is `data-1`. You need to change your while-loop to `while(i < data)` instead of `while(i <= data)`.

The problem is not that you have `data` instead of `10` as the length of the array. The problem is as I stated above: your while-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the while loop. Because arrays are 0 based and you need to only check if `i < data`. By setting it to <=, you are exceeding the array length and generating and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
           while (i < data) {
                int userInput = input.nextInt();
                userArray[i] = userInput;
                i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over-indexing the array. A more standard way for inputting the data would be

```
for ( int i=0; i < data; i++ ) {
   userArray[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```